# migrate git repository on new server

Tags: git

I have 2 servers ( old and new ) on the old one I was working with git but when we switch on the new server all files has been transfer to the new server through FTP and not through Git 
So my question is : Should I delete all the files on the new server and make transfert through git 
Or is there an another to use git on new server ?

Comment: Not enough information here to know. But if you FTP'd the entire `.git` directory from the old server to the new, you've got everything you need.

Comment: So I just have to change the path of the git repository ?

Comment: use git clone to get latest to new server. FTP is not required to copy the code on any git server. If you want to move code from github to bitbucket, delete the .git folder and create new repo in bitbucket and update repo with it.